# WSO2 Analytics 4.4.0 : Problem accessing: /analytics-dashboard. Reason: Not Found

Tags: wso2, analytics, dashboard, api-manager

I just installed WSO2 3.2.0 and Analytics 4.4.0 on the same machine using repositories on Debian 9.

Everything looks fine except the analytics Dashboard that I can't access for. According to the documentation [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/overview-of-api-analytics/), I have to go on this url https://check.mydomain.com:9643/analytics-dashboard but all I got is this error :

> Problem accessing: /analytics-dashboard. Reason: Not Found

**I followed these steps to set up my domain name and enable analytics :**

```
nano /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/repository/conf/deployment.toml
```

> [server]
>
> hostname = "check.mydomain.com"

> [apim.analytics]
>
> enable = true

And I replaced every `"localhost"` string by `${server.hostname}`

**I followed these steps to start Analytics, API Manager and Dashboard :**

```
service wso2sp-4.4.0-worker start
service wso2am-3.2.0 start
service wso2sp-4.4.0-dashboard start
```

**Every service is fine regarding**

```
service wso2sp-4.4.0-worker status
service wso2am-3.2.0 status
service wso2sp-4.4.0-dashboard status
```

**Every other urls are working :**

- https://check.mydomain.com:9443/admin
- https://check.mydomain.com:9443/carbon
- https://check.mydomain.com:9443/devportal
- https://check.mydomain.com:9443/publisher
- Analytics is enabled and I can see subscription options on [Publisher settings](https://check.mydomain.com:9443/publisher/settings)

**Nothing happends on logs when I wisit https://check.mydomain.com:9643/analytics-dashboard**

```
tail -f /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/repository/logs/http_access_.2020-11-18.log
tail -f /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
tail -f /usr/lib/wso2/wso2sp/4.4.0/wso2/worker/logs/carbon.log
tail -f /usr/lib/wso2/wso2sp/4.4.0/wso2/dashboard/logs/carbon.log
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use wso2am analytics setup to configure analytics with the API manager. But I think now you are trying to use wso2 stream processor to configure the analytics and it's not supported with wso2am 3.2.
Follow the [1]documentation to download and set up the analytics.
You need to manually download the wso2am-analytics-3.2.0.zip.

if you follow the quick setup make sure wso2am-analytics-3.2.0 and wso2am folders locate in the same place. (since you installed apim via the apt installer you need to manually put anlytics setup in /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/ folder and correctly set the  path to API manager am_db in wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml--->  AM_DB -> jdbcUrl)

If you follow the standard setup no need to worry about the locations of wso2am pack and wso2am-analytics pack.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/

Comment: You're right, thank you. Now I have other issues with Analytics but I openned a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929323/wso2-3-2-0-analytics-and-dashboard-cannot-borrow-client-on-ssl-port-7712-re) to resolve it