# WSO2 3.2.0 : Analytics and Dashboard, Cannot borrow client on SSL port 7712 + Required field 'message' was not present

Tags: wso2, analytics, dashboard, api-manager

**I installed WSO2 3.2.0 recently :**

- OS : Debian 9
- WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 from the official repository
- WSO2 Analytics 3.2.0 from the zip archive
- Everything running on the same machine with the same domain name
- Valid certificate for this domain name, let's say wso2.mydomain.com

I tried to install Analytics following the [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/), but I think there is a communication issue between analytics worker and API Manager. When I try to go on my dashboard [here](https://wso2.mydomain.com:9643/analytics-dashboard/login), all I got is a blue screen.

**Here are my warns and errors in API Manager logs :**

```
tail -f /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
```

> WARN {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup} - No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} - Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://wso2.mydomain.com:7712. org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://wso2.mydomain.com:7712.
>
> Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Error while trying to login to the data receiver.
>
> Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException

**Here are my warns and errors in Analytics logs :**

```
tail -f /usr/lib/wso2/wso2an/3.2.0/wso2/worker/logs/carbon.log
```

> ERROR {org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer} - Thrift error occurred during processing of message. org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'message' was not present! Struct: ThriftAuthenticationException(message:null)
>
> WARN {org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport} - Error closing output stream. java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed

```
tail -f /usr/lib/wso2/wso2an/3.2.0/wso2/dashboard/logs/carbon.log
```

> WARN {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener} - Error in http connector listener : 'Remote client closed the connection before initiating outbound response'

**Here is my full API Manager deployment config at /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/repository/conf/deployment.toml :**

```
[server]
hostname = "wso2.mydomain.com"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
#offset=0
mode = "single" #single or ha
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "mypassword"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2AM_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[database.shared_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2SHARED_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "owacustom"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[keystore.primary]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "owacustom"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[keystore.internal]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "owacustom"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production and Sandbox"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://wso2.mydomain.com:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://wso2.mydomain.com:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://wso2.mydomain.com:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:${https.nio.port}"

#[apim.cache.gateway_token]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.resource]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.km_token]
#enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.recent_apis]
#enable = false

#[apim.cache.scopes]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.publisher_roles]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.tags]
#expiry_time = "2m"

[apim.analytics]
enable = true
store_api_url = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:7444"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#event_publisher_type = "default"
#event_publisher_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher"
#publish_response_size = true

#[[apim.analytics.url_group]]
#analytics_url =["tcp://wso2.mydomain.com:7611"]
#analytics_auth_url =["ssl://wso2.mydomain.com:7711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.analytics.url_group]]
analytics_url =["tcp://wso2.mydomain.com:7612"]
analytics_auth_url =["ssl://wso2.mydomain.com:7712"]
#type = "failover"

[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/services/"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#pool.init_idle_capacity = 50
#pool.max_idle = 100
#key_validation_handler_type = "default"
#key_validation_handler_type = "custom"
#key_validation_handler_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler"

[apim.idp]
server_url = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443"
authorize_endpoint = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/oauth2/authorize"
oidc_logout_endpoint = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/oidc/logout"
oidc_check_session_endpoint = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/oidc/checksession"

#[apim.jwt]
#enable = true
#encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
#generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
#claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
#convert_dialect = false
#header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
#signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
#enable_user_claims = true
#claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.ExtendedDefaultClaimsRetriever"

[apim.oauth_config]
#enable_outbound_auth_header = false
#auth_header = "Authorization"
revoke_endpoint = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:${https.nio.port}/revoke"
#enable_token_encryption = false
#enable_token_hashing = false

[apim.devportal]
url = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/devportal"
#enable_application_sharing = false
#if application_sharing_type, application_sharing_impl both defined priority goes to application_sharing_impl
#application_sharing_type = "default" #changed type, saml, default #todo: check the new config for rest api
#application_sharing_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.SAMLGroupIDExtractorImpl"
#display_multiple_versions = false
#display_deprecated_apis = false
#enable_comments = true
#enable_ratings = true
#enable_forum = true
#enable_anonymous_mode=true

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey", "testKey"]
allow_credentials = false

[apim.throttling]
#enable_data_publishing = true
#enable_policy_deploy = true
#enable_blacklist_condition = true
#enable_persistence = true
throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://wso2.mydomain.com:5672","tcp://wso2.mydomain.com:5672"]

#[apim.throttling.blacklist_condition]
#start_delay = "5m"
#period = "1h"

#[apim.throttling.jms]
#start_delay = "5m"

#[apim.throttling.event_sync]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 11224

#[apim.throttling.event_management]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 10005

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://wso2.mydomain.com:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://wso2.mydomain.com:9711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://wso2.mydomain.com.com:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://wso2.mydomain.com:9711"]
#type = "failover"

[apim.workflow]
#enable = false
service_url = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9445/bpmn"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
callback_endpoint = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/api/am/admin/v0.17/workflows/update-workflow-status"
token_endpoint = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:${https.nio.port}/token"
client_registration_endpoint = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/client-registration/v0.17/register"
#client_registration_username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#client_registration_password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

#data bridge config
#[transport.receiver]
#type = "binary"
#worker_threads = 10
#session_timeout = "30m"
#keystore.file_name = "$ref{keystore.tls.file_name}"
#keystore.password = "$ref{keystore.tls.password}"
#tcp_port = 9611
#ssl_port = 9711
#ssl_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#tcp_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#ssl_enabled_protocols = ["TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"]
#ciphers = ["SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5","SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"]

[apim.notification]
#from_address = "APIM.com"
#username = "APIM"
#password = "APIM+123"
hostname = "wso2.mydomain.com"
#port = 3025
#enable_start_tls = false
#enable_authentication = true

apim.token.revocation]
#notifier_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.events.TokenRevocationNotifierImpl"
#enable_realtime_notifier = true
#realtime_notifier.ttl = 5000
#enable_persistent_notifier = true
persistent_notifier.hostname = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:2379/v2/keys/jti/"
#persistent_notifier.ttl = 5000
#persistent_notifier.username = "root"
#persistent_notifier.password = "root"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[database.local]
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"

[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1
[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"

# Remove "WSO2 Carbon Server" from server value in header response
[transport.http.properties]
server="wso2.mydomain.com"

# Intermediate compatibility (recommended) ciphers list see https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS
[transport.https.sslHostConfig.properties]
ciphers="TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305, ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305, DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
```

**Here is the lines I added to the API Manager boostrap file on /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/bin/wso2server.sh :**

```
-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 \
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true \
```

**I just modified the super admin password in my worker deployment file at /usr/lib/wso2/wso2an/3.2.0/conf/worker/deployment.yaml :**

```
# Authentication configuration
auth.configs:
  type: 'local'        # Type of the IdP client used
  userManager:
    adminRole: admin   # Admin role which is granted all permissions
    userStore:         # User store
      users:
       -
         user:
           username: admin
           password: bXlwYXNzd29yZA==
           roles: 1
      roles:
       -
         role:
           id: 1
           displayName: admin

  # Configuration to enable apim alerts
#analytics.solutions:
#  APIM-alerts.enabled: true
```

**And I replaced some localhost values by my domain name + modified the super admin password in my dashboard deployment file at /usr/lib/wso2/wso2an/3.2.0/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml :**

```
## Authentication configuration
auth.configs:
  type: apim
  ssoEnabled: true
  properties:
    adminScope: apim_analytics:admin_carbon.super
    allScopes: apim_analytics:admin openid apim:api_view apim:subscribe apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:own apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:edit apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:view apim_analytics:business_analytics:own apim_analytics:business_analytics:edit apim_analytics:business_analytics:view apim_analytics:api_analytics:own apim_analytics:api_analytics:edit apim_analytics:api_analytics:view apim_analytics:application_analytics:own apim_analytics:application_analytics:edit
    adminUsername: admin
    adminPassword: mypassword
    kmDcrUrl: https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/client-registration/v0.17/register
    kmTokenUrlForRedirection: https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/oauth2
    kmTokenUrl: https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/oauth2
    kmUsername: admin
    kmPassword: admin
    portalAppContext: analytics-dashboard
    businessRulesAppContext : business-rules
    cacheTimeout: 30
    baseUrl: https://wso2.mydomain.com:9643
    grantType: authorization_code
    publisherUrl: https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443
    devPortalUrl: https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443
    externalLogoutUrl: https://wso2.mydomain.com:9443/oidc/logout
```

**Also, my client-truststore.jks and wso2carbon.jks files are the same for both products :**

- /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/repository/resources/security
- /usr/lib/wso2/wso2an/3.2.0/resources/security

Am I missing something? Thanks by advance!

Comment: your api manager is running without any errors?

Comment: No there is an error, I quoted it at the beginning of my post. I'll edit my question to separate API Manager and Analytics errors.

Comment: can you disable analytics first and check whether the API manager is running without any errors?

Comment: Sure. It gives me no error but some warns :
`WARN {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase} - jsseUtil.trustedCertNotValid`
`WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSUtils} - Cannot locate destination : keyManager / throttleData / notification / cacheInvalidation / tokenRevocation`

Answer (score 0):

can you check whether wso2am-analytics-3.2.0/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml---> AM_DB -> jdbcUrl path was correctly configured to your wso2 API manager am_db. Maybe your path is incorrect and should change it according to your path.

Comment: It was incorrect, thanks. I changed it to "jdbc:h2:/usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.2.0/repository/database/WSO2AM_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE". But I'm still unable to visit my dashboard. I have an invalid credentials message eror, wether I place "mypassword" or its base64 in deployment workers and dashboard files.